# Is it possible to use use Nginx 32bit with php 64bit?

Tags: php, nginx, webserver

Am new to PHP and Nginx web server. I want to setup a 64bit Nginx web server with PHP 5.6 64bit on Windows 64bit system, but only 32bit Nginx build is available for windows officially. Is it possible to use PHP 64bit with Nginx 32bit web server?
If it is possible to use it, is there any performance impact?

There are 64bit Nginx builds available from unofficial sources, but they advice not to use this for production, so I need to stick with official 32bit Nginx build for windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, why a windows production server?

Comment: Only Windows is allowed at our organisation.

Comment: In that case - i'm wondering: if it's windows server 2012 where IIS is improved, and you can run php as fastcgi - why introduce a 3rd party web server that you need to ensure is up to date.

Comment: Good suggestion, thank you. Will check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP with nginx would normally be run as a fastcgi application (https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/ ).

This would communicate over a TCP socket on windows - and therefore it doesn't matter whether it's 64bit or 32bit php at the far end.

In terms of PHP, if performance is a key driver, and your new - you mind want to consider looking at php 7 as that has a number of performance improvements over the php5 series. The development of php 7 has some benchmarks on a google docs spreadsheet at the bottom of their page https://wiki.php.net/phpng which indicates the differences